# Docker image doesn't find the path to make work a cmd bash.sh file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have built a Docker image which calls a bash file and processes some files in a specific folder, but I can't manage to make it run/work. I have tried different approaches but cannot find where the issue is. Building an image with

```sh
docker build -t user/mycontainer .
```

works, but the bash script doesn't run when I

```sh
docker run mycontainer `pwd`:/app
```

Instead it produces an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/path/c/to/where/i/run/teh/docker:/app": stat /path/c/to/where/i/run/teh/docker:/app: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

When I run `docker ps` there aren't any containers,  but if I `docker ps -a` the container just built appears.

I try running

```sh
docker exec -it <container id build> bash
```

and I get a different error response from daemon:

```
Container <container id build> is not running
```

The docker image seems to build all the dependencies and the bash code works when run it separately in my local within the folder.

My dockerfile looks:

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Create directory in container image for app code
RUN mkdir -p /app

# Copy app code (.) to /app in container image
COPY . /app

# Set working directory context


ARG TIPPECANOE_RELEASE="1.36.0"

RUN apk add --no-cache sudo git g++ make libgcc libstdc++ sqlite-libs sqlite-dev zlib-dev bash \
 && addgroup sudo && adduser -G sudo -D -H tippecanoe && echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers \
 && cd /root \
 && git clone https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe.git tippecanoe \
 && cd tippecanoe \
 && git checkout tags/$TIPPECANOE_RELEASE \
 && cd /root/tippecanoe \
 && make \
 && make install \
 && cd /root \
 && rm -rf /root/tippecanoe \
 && apk del git g++ make sqlite-dev


RUN chmod +x ./app/bash.sh

USER tippecanoe

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["./bash.sh"]
```

Comment: what if you use absolute path in CMD?

Comment: absolute path to the folder where i want it to run the bash code? or to where the dockerfile is? sorry im layman in this field

Comment: absolute path of bash.sh.

Comment: yes i tried but still the same

Comment: please paste **exact** `docker run` command and error message, don't obsfucate the path. i think they should be in one screen of command line output.

Comment: doesnt show any error,  but doesnt looks like is not building either now.

Comment: Check line endings in bash.sh. My experience is that windows line endings (CRLF) sometimes cause this error and unix endings (LF) work.

Comment: @AndreasJagiella Im using vscode i have the crlf end line sequence already (is that was the correct one isnt?)

Comment: no you need LF line endlings for the script

Comment: @jr.gcj let me know if it helped

Comment: The `$(pwd)/app` at the end of the `docker run` command is being interpreted as the command to run.  I'd recommend just deleting it.  You might see options like that intended as a developer-oriented setup to run different code than what's built into the Docker image; for that you need a `-v` option, and the option and the path need to appear before the image name.

Comment: @AndreasJagiella thanks i have changed it but nothing at all...

Comment: You don't need that path option at all and you should delete it; just `docker run myimage`.  The script is built into the image already.

Comment: @DavidMaze  `docker run -v ./path/to/folder/with/files/bash/code/needs/to/run/  <image id>` it returns like the first line of the bash but doesnt run it complettelly returns (`++ find . -name '*.json'`) when i run docker ps -a seems that run and the status is exited (0)

Comment: and how i point to the folder where the .json files are? when running docker run  <my image> does the same

Comment: since you are not setting the workdir before i would suggest also changing `RUN chmod +x ./app/bash.sh` to `RUN chmod +x /app/bash.sh` . The line before requires your workdir to be at / but im not sure if thats the case with alpine

Comment: But as @DavidMaze said, you just need to run `docker run myimage` otherwise it will not work